# Trying to create a view and I am getting an error stating ORA-00904: "JOB": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE VIEW emp_view AS 
SELECT empno AS "Employee Number", ename AS "Employee Name", NVL(sal * 26 + comm * 12 ,0) as "Gross Salary", job , loc as "Location" 
FROM dept;
```

Create a View called emp_view that is a join of the emp table and the dept table. The view consists of a SQL query that shows the empno, ename, sal * 26 + comm * 12 (don’t forget the NVL() function on COMM ), the job and the loc from the dept table.

This view is for the Human Resources department, and will consist of the following columns:

Empno will show in the view as “Employee Number”

Ename will show as “Employee Name”

Job you can leave as JOB

Loc will show in the view as “Location”

Comment: Does the `dept` table have a column `JOB` ?  This is the first thing to check.

Comment: yes it does have the column job in the dept table

Answer (score 0):

The error message is straightforward, there is no column named JOB in table DPT.

In the question, it is mentionned that :

> emp_view is a join of the emp table and the dept table

So my guess is that the JOB column actually comes from the EMP table. Hence in the definition of your view you should join DEPT with EMP instead of using DEPT only.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer seems you are trying to create a view from a join between emp and dept table. Error message clearly says that column used in view does not exists in the "dept" table which you are using in your view. If you can post the structure of emp table that will help to give you correct answer.

But based on the limited information given in your example you may want to try to join both tables something like - 
From emp INNER JOIN dept on emp.deptID=dept.deptID